# Angular Material Select w/ Columns

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, multiple-columns

I am trying to style the selection panel such that the items display in several columns, but the last item of each column seems to become off-center and split, with the overflow starting at the top of the next column. Ideally the scroll would be vertical, but instead it seems to scroll horizontal to cover the overflow. My list has 30+ items and multiple selections are allowed. The goal is to display as many options as possible to the user at once so they don't have to scroll too much.

Full StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt3gs6

[image: Panel Screenshot]

**select-multiple-example.scss**

```
.toppings-panel.mat-select-panel {
  column-count: 2;
  column-width: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

**select-multiple-example.html**

```
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" panelClass="toppings-panel" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

**select-multiple-example.ts**

```
export class SelectMultipleExample {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  toppingList: string[] = ['Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Ham', 'Bacon', 'Chicken', 
                           'Mushroom', 'Red onion', 'White onion', 'Tomato', 'Olives', 
                           'Green bell peppers', 'Pineapple', 'Artichoke', 'Spinach', 
                           'Basil', 'Hot pepper flakes', 
                           'Parmesan', 'Shredded cheddar', 'Extra mozzarella'];
}
```

Comment: Your Stackblitz does not seem to include the code posted in your question

Comment: Apologies, my StackBlitz skills are a bit rusty. :) I've updated the link in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the columns that become off-center and split, is the height of the `.mat-select-panel`.

It has `max-height:256px;` (setted in Angular Material code). But, since it has a horizontal scrollbar (which has a height of `17px`, in Windows - Chrome), the available remaining space will be: 256 - 17 = **239px**.

The height of the `mat-option` is 48px, so 5 options in a column will take **240px**.

A quick solution would be to increase the height of the `.mat-select-panel` to `257px`:

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt3gs6-wxwkgg

But, the example above will not display correctly on MacOS; which displays scrollbars like an absolute positioned content, and it has more space available:

[image]

---

I've found a cross platform solution by removing columns (which are kind of difficult to implement cross-browser and cross-platform) and taking an 
approach with `display: flex` for the `.mat-select-panel` element:

**Horizontal scrolling**:

```
.toppings-panel.mat-select-panel {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 257px;   // min-height needed for windows browsers
}

 .toppings-panel.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
   min-width: 50%;  // 50% to have 2 columns visible
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt3gs6-lwvwav

**Vertical scrolling**:

If you prefer vertical scrolling, just remove `flex-direction: column;` from the code above and play with the `max-height` in order to set the default visible rows:

```
.toppings-panel.mat-select-panel {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  max-height: 240px; /* 240px - for 5 items / column */
}

.toppings-panel.mat-select-panel .mat-option {
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt3gs6-iykn4w

Comment: I'd really like to scroll down instead of across to see more options, but this looks pretty clean so I'll take it! Thanks a million.

Comment: It seems that I really haven't read the part of your question that you prefer scroll down. Please check an updated example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt3gs6-iykn4w

Comment: Hi @andreivictor, do you have any idea why selection of items cause a scroll of the pane when you select items and the scroll bar is not at the top or bottom?

Comment: This is the default behaviour from `Material Select`...  See: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/70ff528785cb9abe9f102f19b1ea87caef56a295/src/material/select/select.ts#L902.  I don't think there is a way to disable it